# In perl, Is there a more compact way to search for a number of patterns, and for each one, substitute with an expression

Tags: regex, perl, replace

In perl, I am reading a line and trying to replace a set of strings with corresponding expressions using a sequence of if statements. For example:

```
my @shiftInstructions=("lsr", "lsl", "rol", "ror");
while (my $line = <>) {
  if ($line =~ /\$sh/) {
    my $r = int(rand(6));
    $line =~ s/\$sh/$r/;
  }
  if ($line =~ /\$ish/) {
    my $r = $shiftInstructions[rand(4)]
    $line =~ s/\$ish/$r/;
  }
}
```

I don't like this approach for a number of reasons. First, it is repetitive. I have to first check if the pattern exists, and then if it does, execute a function to generate a replacement value, then substitute. So it is both verbose, and slow (2 regex searches per pattern, perhaps eventually dozens of pattern strings).

I thought of a map where a number of codes are mapped to corresponding code to execute.

I can imagine mapping to a string and then using eval but then I can't check the code except at runtime. Is there any cleaner way of doing this?

I found the execute option in regex. What about writing a set of subroutines to process each regex, then creating a mapping:

```
my %regexMap = (
    "\$fn", &foundFunc,
    "\$hw", &hex8,
    "\$hb", &hex2,
    "\$sh", &rand6,
    "\$ish", &shiftInst,
    );
while (my $line = <>) {
    $line =~ s/(\$fn|\$hw|\$hb|\$sh|\$ish|)/$regexMap{$1}/e;    
    print $line;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($line =~ /\$sh/) {
   my $r = int(rand(6));
   $line =~ s/\$sh/$r/;
}
```

is a poor way of writing

```
$line =~ s/\$sh/ int(rand(6)) /e;
```

So

```
my @shiftInstructions=("lsr", "lsl", "rol", "ror");
while (my $line = <>) {
  if ($line =~ /\$sh/) {
    my $r = int(rand(6));
    $line =~ s/\$sh/$r/;
  }
  if ($line =~ /\$ish/) {
    my $r = $shiftInstructions[rand(4)]
    $line =~ s/\$ish/$r/;
  }
  print($line);
}
```

can be written as

```
my @shiftInstructions = qw( lsr lsl rol ror );

while (my $line = <>) {
   $line =~ s/\$sh/ int(rand(6)) /e;
   $line =~ s/\$ish/ $shiftInstructions[rand(@shiftInstructions)] /e;
   print($line);
}
```

But that means you are scanning the string over and over again. Let's avoid that.

```
my @shiftInstructions = qw( lsr lsl rol ror );

while (my $line = <>) {
   $line =~ s/\$(sh|ish)/
      if    ( $1 eq "sh"  ) { int(rand(6)) }
      elsif ( $1 eq "ish" ) { $shiftInstructions[rand(@shiftInstructions)] }
   /eg;
   print($line);
}
```

Unfortunately, that reintroduces repetition. We can solve that using a dispatch table.

```
my @shiftInstructions = qw( lsr lsl rol ror );

my %replacements = (
   sh  => sub { int(rand(6)) },
   ish => sub { $shiftInstructions[rand(@shiftInstructions)] },
);

my $alt = join '|', map quotemeta, keys(%replacements);
my $re = qr/\$($alt)/;

while (my $line = <>) {
   print $line =~ s/$re/ $replacements{$1}->() /reg;
}
```

Now we have an efficient solution that can be extended without slowing down the matching, all while avoiding repetition.

---

The solution you added to your question was close, but it had two bugs.

1. `&foo` calls `foo`. To get a reference to it, use `\&foo`.

   ```
   my %regexMap = (
       "\$fn", \&foundFunc,
       "\$hw", \&hex8,
       "\$hb", \&hex2,
       "\$sh", \&rand6,
       "\$ish", \&shiftInst,
       );
   ```
2. `$regexMap{$1}` now returns the reference. You want to call the referenced sub, which can be done using `$regexMap{$1}->()`.

   ```
   while (my $line = <>) {
       $line =~ s/(\$fn|\$hw|\$hb|\$sh|\$ish|)/ $regexMap{$1}->() /e;
       print $line;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

In these cases, I often make some sort of data structure that holds the patterns and their actions:

```
my @tuples = (
    [ qr/.../, sub { ... } ]
    [ ... ].
    );
```

Now the meat of the process stays the same no matter how many patterns I want to try:

```
while( <> ) {
    foreach $tuple ( @tuples ) {
        $tuple->[1]() if /$tuple[0]/
        }
     }
```

Abstract this a little further with a subroutine that takes the data structure. Then you can pass it different tables depending on what you would like to do:

```
sub some_sub {
    my @tuples = @_;

    while( <> ) {
        foreach $tuple ( @tuples ) {
            $tuple->[1]() if /$tuple[0]/
            }
         }
    }
```

I've written about this sort of thing in [Mastering Perl](https://www.masteringperl.org) and [Effective Perl Programming](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming), and it's the sort of thing that does into my obscure modules like [Brick](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/Brick) and [Data::Constraint](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/Data::Constraint).

---

I've been thinking about this more, and I wonder if regexes are actually part of what you are trying to do. It looks like you are matching literal strings, but using the match operator to do it. You don't give details of the input, so I'm guessing here—it looks like there's an operation (e.g. `$fn`, and you want to match exactly that operation. The problem is finding that string then mapping it onto code. That looks something like this (and ikegami's answer is another form of this idea). Instead of an alternation, I match anything that might look like the string:

```
while( <> ) {
    # find the string. Need example input to guess better
    if( m/(\$[a-z]+)/ ) {
        $table{$1}->() if exists $table{$1};
        }
    }
```

But again, it's dependent on the input, how many actual substrings you might want to match (so, the number of branches in an alternation), how many lines you want to process, and so on. There was a wonderful talk about processing apache log files with [Regex::Trie](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Trie) and the various experiments they tried to make things faster. I've forgotten all the details, but very small adjustments made noticeable differences over tens of millions of lines.

Interesting reading:

- Maybe this talk? [An exploration of trie regexp matching](http://blogs.perl.org/users/yapceurope_2012/2012/07/an-exploration-of-trie-regexp-matching.html)
- http://taint.org/2006/07/07/184022a.html
- [Matching a long list of phrases](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=567242)

Comment: That is more elegant, but you are still processing a lot of regexes. I just found the execute option on the regex. I will edit to add what I found but if there is a reason against please let me know.

Comment: You adjust this for what you need to do. You didn't ask about how to choose which set of patterns to check, and at some point you have to decide which set you want to check.

Answer (score -1):

OP's code can be written in following form

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %regexMap = (
    '$fn'   => \&foundFunc,
    '$hw'   => \&hex8,
    '$hb'   => \&hex2,
    '$sh'   => \&rand6,
    '$ish'  => \&shiftInst,
    );

my @keys = map { "\\$_" } keys %regexMap;
my $re = join('|', @keys);

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    next unless /($re)/;
    $regexMap{$1}->();
}

sub foundFunc   { say 'sub_foundFunc' }
sub hex8        { say 'sub_hex8'      }
sub hex2        { say 'sub_hex2'      }
sub rand6       { say 'sub_rand6'     }
sub shiftInst   { say 'sub_shiftInst' }

__DATA__
$fn
$hw
$ac
$hb
$sh
$fn
$mf
$hb
$ish
$hw
```

Output

```
sub_foundFunc
sub_hex8
sub_hex2
sub_rand6
sub_foundFunc
sub_hex2
sub_shiftInst
sub_hex8
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It calls each sub once, and exactly once, regardless of the input. Even if you fix that, it still doesn't do what the OP wants contrary to your claims.